# Is safe pass the NavigationController as reference in a Custom View?

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm new in the android programming and I've created a Custom View that show a bottom menu. I must do it custom (without the material components) for needs.

[image: The bottom menu]

The purpose of this custom view is to let the user navigate in some fragments that handle specific customer options.

I implemented it on the MainActivity (the only activity for the application), as it must be shown only in some fragment in the middle of the application (the fragments for the customer informations).

The main problem was to create the navigation for the custom view. 
The main error at the begin was

```
 View com.customviews.customerbottom.CustomMenuView{c9abff2 V.E...... ........ 26,1573-1054,1678 #7f0a00c1 app:id/customer_bottom_menu} does not have a NavController set
```

To handle this problem I've pass the NavController from the MainActivity into the CustomView through a setter.

**MainActivity Code**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   // {... Other Setup Code...}
    // Ref to the navigation
    navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

    // Ref to the custom view
    customMenuView = binding.customerBottomMenu

    // Setter method
    customMenuView.setNavController(navController)

   // {... Other Setup Code...}
    }
```

**Custom View Code**

```
class CustomMenuView : LinearLayout {

  private var navController : NavController? = null
  private var clickableIcon : CustomMenuViewIcon? = null

  //{constructors}

  override fun onFinishInflate(){
    //{ inflatter and layout creation}

    clickableIcon =
          inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_icon_bottom_menu, this, false) as 
          CustomerMenuIconView?

     clickableIcon?.setOnClickListener{
          navController?.navigate(*ToDestination)
     }
  }

   fun setNavController(nc : NavController){
       navController = nc   
   }
}
```

The question is: how dangerous is to pass the navController in this way? Should I avoid this way to navigate with the custom views?

Thanks!

Comment: For better codding practise, view should just notify click events, in your case you can use a custom interface callback.